# The direct update doesn't work in MobileFirst Studio v7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm doing a demo in MF Studio 7.1, but I can not make the direct update work in the studio, I have test on at leat 3 workstations. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the Direct Update tutorial, and specifically the following section: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/#underTheHood

---

Because MobileFirst Platform Foundation Server 7.1 is *session-independent*, this affects Direct Update as well.
The setting of when to check for a Direct Update is now based on *tokens*; the check for an update will be made only once the token expires.

You can adjust it in the following ways:

1. Remove the wl_DirectUpdate realm from the used security test in authenticationConfig.xml and instead explicitly call the  `WL.Client.checkForDirectUpdate` API to check for an update
2. Change the `wl.realm.expiration.directUpdate` value in the your-project\server\conf\worklight.properties file to a lower value.

Note for production environments: The lower the value, the more network traffic will incur. The value should be configured with care.